# Calculate standard deviation of certain columns in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics

I have a data frame with 120 rows and 265 columns. Cells from column 5 to column 265 contain a numerical value.

For every single row I want to calculate the standard deviation of the values of every odd column from column 5 to column 265 (column 5, column 7, column 9, and so on) and write it into column 266 of the respective row.

I crunched around with apply function and for loops for two hours now but all I get is error messages I can't make sense of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try

```
df$newCol <- apply(df[seq(5, ncol(df), by=2)], 1, sd)
```

Or use `rowSds` from `matrixStats`

```
library(matrixStats)
df$newCol <-  rowSds(as.matrix(df[seq(5, ncol(df), by=2)]))
```

Or as commented by @DavidArenburg, you can check the vectorized [`RowSD`](https://gist.github.com/DavidArenburg/cca995ec1709c0d4735d)

#### data

```
set.seed(253)
df <- cbind(as.data.frame(matrix(sample(letters, 120*4, replace=TRUE),
  ncol=4), stringsAsFactors=FALSE), matrix(sample(1:50, 120*261, 
 replace=TRUE), ncol=261))
```

Comment: You could also try my awesome (vectorized) [`RowSD`](https://gist.github.com/DavidArenburg/cca995ec1709c0d4735d) :)

Comment: @DavidArenburg  Thanks for sharing it. Any plans to create package  in the near future?

Comment: As soon as I'll write them using the `Rcpp` package probably. For now, these functions just a bit more efficient...

Comment: Thanks for the answer akrun, but it just doesn't work either. I get the same error message concerning some "50 warnings..." just as with my attempts. I can't understand what might be wrong here since i already performed half a dozen other operations on this data frame, some of them with apply functions and different elements you mentioned and they all worked like a charm.

I guess i'll copy and paste the data into spss or excel and do it there.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: @MichaelHeinisch Please check if one of the columns is not numeric in the `5:ncol(yourdata)`  i.e. `str(yourdata)`

Comment: yes, you are right. the 5th column is of type character all of a sudden although i am certain, i never touched its datatype. And every attempt to convert it back to numeric or double in R only produces NAs. Working with R surely is interesting ^^.

Comment: @MichaelHeinisch If there are numeric elements in that "character" class column, it will be converted to numeric elements and all other non-numeric elements get coerced to NAs.  i.e. `yourdata[,5] <- as.numeric(yourdata[,5])` and there will be a warning for the coercion.  If you have factor column, convert to character, then to numeric.

Comment: thank you for your help. I just figured out, where the non-numeric elements came from. I was supplied with the data only in a different file format, that uses ',' as decimal point instead of '.'. So some variables with decimal values were interpreted by R as text...

I got it now, thanks again. :-)